# How to open new tab in browser (in same browser window) with TestCafe?

Tags: tabs, automated-tests, cross-browser, ui-automation, testcafe

I am currently unable to open a new tab in the same browser window. Please refer scenario.

- After login, the application opens the page in the same browser
  window. I need to click on the card and after it will open in a new
  tab and where I need to test everything. Currently, I need to
  simulate a direct URL for a new tab but I want to open a new tab with
  test case code.

Please let me know is it possible in the test cafe?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [Multiple Browser Windows](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows) testing API? If you faced difficulties with this API, please describe them in greater detail. Note that TestCafe Studio does not support recording tests in multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass --disableNewWindow in testcafe/runner argument to open url in same tab.

Also, refer to https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows#disable-support-for-multiple-windows
--disable-multiple-windows